# Using PHPExcel to make automatic generated excel files

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I want to have my excel file filled with some data which I get from my database, for example the name and age of someone.

Say there are 10 people in my database. I want those 10 people in my Excel file.

So basically, you would get:

NAME   AGE

Person1 20 years

Person2 25 years

And so on. I know how to set the NAME and AGE stuff, but how would I go about looping the data and writing it inside the excel file? I couldn't find anything about it in PHPExcel's documentation.

This is my MySQL:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM bestelling"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $age = $row['age'];
}
```

Comment: edited answer as per your code :-) Kindly check.

Comment: Is that working for you?

Comment: Take a look at http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/246121/ for an example

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'm assuming you already have the excel object created. I'll call it $objPHPExcel to conform to their examples. In that case you can loop your result set and populate the spreadsheet this way:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$rowCount = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['name']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['age']);
    $rowCount++;
}
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('some_excel_file.xlsx');
```

EDIT: I have updated the example to provide a complete solution.

Comment: This won't write any data to my excel file, maybe you missed something?

Comment: @Andre, I have updated my answer to provide the complete solution. I was assuming you had read the example and were already creating the excel object and calling the $objWriter->save() method. Does it work for you now?

Comment: @Andre - what exactly doesn't work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: As Mark asked, what errors are you getting? What isn't working?

Comment: Thanks @davidethell I use your code. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Here is complete code for create the excel file :

```
require "PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php";
require "PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php"; 

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Govinda")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Govinda")
                             ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");

// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(5);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(25);


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Sr no')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'Name')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Age')


// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['name']);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['age']);
      $rowCount++;
}

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('UserList');
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="userList.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```